# Which collection should use when writer thread exceeds reader thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

The below question asked me in an interview--
When the number of writer threads is more than reader then the performance of the ConcurrentHashMap degrades then in that case which collection we should use?

And also need to know how many writer and reader thread can access CHM simultaneously.
please explain or provide some links.
Thanks

Comment: Very strange interview question. Slows down compared to what? Somebody showing off again. This is the sort of thing I would expect an employee to investigate rather than know off the top of his head.

Comment: There seem to be some details/constraints missing. `ConcurrentHashMap` handles simultaneous reading/writing just fine. [To quote the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): "Retrieval operations generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations." The performance only goes down the drain when the `ConcurrentHashMap` needs to be resized. But that is not a function of the number of writers.

Comment: ok Thanks for the reply